# Using Mysql Set Field Type

Tags: mysql

I want to implement a badge modification to my website, i  figured that I would have one new column in my mysql database to store number variables in them, and then i can display badges based on what number is in the mysql column for each user, should i use the SET field type to accomplish this?

Comment: How many badges might a user have?

Comment: i was going to have around 30-40 or so

Comment: To be clear, you're saying that a single user may at one time have 30-40 badges?  Or each user will have only one badge of 30-40?  Or...?

Comment: each user may at one time have 30 or different badges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you create two tables:

1. `badges`, containing the details of each badge;
2. `userbadges`, containing a pair of foreign keys - that of a user and that of a badge owned by that user.

This has the advantage over `SET` of enabling you to add/delete/change badges without altering your schema and also to reference badges from other tables with minimum duplication.

Comment: what is a pair of foreign keys?? and which field type should i have these as?

Comment: @spaceranger: A "key" is a set of fields that uniquely identify records in a table (could merely be a single integer `id` number, but could equally be any combination of datatypes provided that in your data structure they meet this requirement).  A "foreign key" is a set of fields that uniquely identify records in some other table: for example `user_id` and `badge_id`.

Comment: i see and what field type should the badges and the userbadges field be?

Comment: @spaceranger: In my answer they're *tables*, not *fields*.

Comment: so 2 new tables? i thought making columns would mean less overhead, what is the advantage of doing it by creating 2 tables?

Comment: "*This has the advantage over `SET` of enabling you to add/delete/change badges without altering your schema and also to reference badges from other tables with minimum duplication*".